# How to Use Ajax and post data request on another URL?

Tags: ajax

How to Use Ajax and post data request on another URL?
solve ajax Issue

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'https://kyleschaeffer.com/feed/',
      data: { postVar1: 'theValue1', postVar2: 'theValue2' },
      beforeSend:function(){
        // this is where we append a loading image
        $('#ajax-panel').html('<div class="loading"><img src="/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
      },
      success:function(data){});
    });
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? You posted a code-snipped, which is nice. But I don't understand, what works or what you expect out of it. Please add some more information,.

Answer (score 0):

**This jQuery function is perfect in the sense that it handles 99% of all the AJAX requests you’ll ever need to make, it includes a success and failure function to ensure that users get the proper feedback they need, and you’ll get a spinning loading image while the request is being processed to boot.**

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://kyleschaeffer.com/feed/',
  data: { postVar1: 'theValue1', postVar2: 'theValue2' },
  beforeSend:function(){
    // this is where we append a loading image
    $('#ajax-panel').html('<div class="loading"><img src="/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
  },
  success:function(data){
    // successful request; do something with the data
    $('#ajax-panel').empty();
    $(data).find('item').each(function(i){
      $('#ajax-panel').append('<h4>' + $(this).find('title').text() + '</h4><p>' + $(this).find('link').text() + '</p>');
    });
  },
  error:function(){
    // failed request; give feedback to user
    $('#ajax-panel').html('<p class="error"><strong>Oops!</strong> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
  }
});
```